# Python and Bluefish editor

Tags: python, bluefish

I am using Mac OS. I would like to know how can I invoke python interpreter directly from Bluefish editor ?

I would like to know what command should I type near the word "Python" to invoke interpreter directly from this text editor

[image: Concerning question]

Comment: Nope, not possible with `Bluefish`. It's possible with `Aptana Studio`

Comment: Thx for advise. I have chose Aptana Studio, better then my first decision.

Answer (score 0):

simply write `python '%f'` and it should work just fine (at least it works under linux after starting bluefish from commandline itself)